# How to use Zend_Db_Table with many to many relationships

Tags: php, zend-framework, many-to-many, relational-database

How can I use Zend's [Zend_Db_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html) with [many to many relationships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) with a junction table? Is there any built in method providing this fictionality or have to write simple SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the documentation: [Fetching a Rowset via a Many-to-many Relationship](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html#zend.db.table.relationships.fetching.many-to-many)

To fetch a row:

```
$row->findManyToManyRowset($table,
                           $intersectionTable,
                           [$rule1,
                               [$rule2,
                                   [Zend_Db_Table_Select $select]
                               ]
                           ]);
// Example
$productsRowset = $bug1234->findManyToManyRowset('Products',
                                                 'BugsProducts');
// Here, BugsProducts is the junction table
```

But, as for a one-to-many relationship, you need to also define the relation in the classes: [Defining relationships](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html#zend.db.table.relationships.defining).